# Why are all of my dropdown menus a blank black screen?

Tags: xfce, menu

I recently updated my ubuntu 16.04 system and now all the drop down menus are black. It starts up fine and looks normal until i open an app or click on a menu. I can not read or click anything in the menu. The only desktop environment I can get to work is Xfce. It works fine. Even the windows in the Ubuntu desktop environment have black squares around them and will not allow me the select them or move them around the desktop. Anyone ever experience this??

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to graphics drivers.

Today I had the same problem and I fixed it like this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you have any graphical errors it shows the packages you have to install or upgrade.

I saw errors about

```
libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libmirclient-dev libmircommon-dev libmircookie-dev libmircookie2 libprotobuf-dev libxkbcommon-dev
```

so I fixed it by installing those packages

```
sudo apt-get install libllvm3.8 libllvm3.8:i386 libmirclient-dev libmircommon-dev libmircookie-dev libmircookie2 libprotobuf-dev libxkbcommon-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a well-known and longstanding bug in Linux >4.2, and specifically 4.3 and 4.4. See here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=209065

I just got it in 14.04 again and restarting rather than shutting laptop should make it not happen... or downgrade or upgrade your kernel :(